# Problems using a class that implements Comparator as a parameter

Tags: java, sorting, generics, parameters, comparator

I have a map that needs to be sorted with very specific conditions, so I created the following class:

```
private class EventComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Event, gohs.scyoly.core.Entry>> {

    Crew crew;

    public EventComparator(Crew crew) {
        this.crew = crew;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(java.util.Map.Entry<Event, Entry> o1,
            java.util.Map.Entry<Event, Entry> o2) {

        // algorithm for comparing
    }

}
```

I then created a separate static class and function that would use bubble sort:

```
public static <K, V> void mapSort(LinkedHashMap<K, V> map,
            Comparator<Map.Entry<? super K, ? super V>> comparator) {

        // array list is more efficient
        ArrayList<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
        int i; // var for iterating
        boolean swap = true; // false if no swaps occurred (list is sorted)
        Map.Entry<K, V> temp;

        while(swap) {
            swap = false; // assume no swap will occur
            for (i = 0; i < entries.size() -1; i++)
                if (comparator.compare(entries.get(i), entries.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                    temp = entries.get(i);
                    entries.set(i, entries.get(i + 1));
                    entries.set(i + 1, temp);
                    swap = true;
                }
        }

        // re-factor the original map
        map.clear();
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries)
            map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

The important thing to note is the parameters that the function takes. I thought that i could simply do the following: `mapSort(sorted, new EventComparator(crew))` but Eclipse warns me that the second parameter is not of the correct type. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

As requested by Tim, here is the code that calls it:

```
    // Reduce team size if necessary
    if (crew.getSize() > 15) {
        System.out.println("Crew reduction neccessary"); // DEBUG

        // get list of the next step down in feeder
        LinkedHashMap<Event, gohs.scyoly.core.Entry> sorted = new LinkedHashMap<>(feeder.size());

        for (Map.Entry<Event, Stack<Entry>> feederEntry : feeder.entrySet()) {
            sorted.put(feederEntry.getKey(), feederEntry.getValue().peek());
        }

        BubbleSort.mapSort(sorted, new EventComparator(crew));

        System.out.println(sorted.entrySet()); // DEBUG
    }
```

For context, the application aims to scan in team scores for events, which get stored as entries, and then output the perfect "crew", which is a collection of teams that compete in the events together.

*Update:*
I changed the code to the following:

```
BubbleSort.mapSort(sorted, (Comparator<Map.Entry<Event, gohs.scyoly.core.Entry>>) new EventComparator(crew));
```

But it still gives me an error with the following message:

`The method mapSort(LinkedHashMap<K,V>, Comparator<Map.Entry<? super K,? super V>>) in the type Assembler.BubbleSort is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedHashMap<Event,Entry>, Comparator<Map.Entry<Event,Entry>>)`

Comment: Please show us the code which calls `mapSort()`.

Comment: Why not using  a `TreeMap` created with your comparator (`new TreeMap(new EventComparator(...))`) which does the sorting for you? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: That was my first solution, but I was forced to change because TreeMap cannot handle duplicates

Comment: For the signature for `sortMap`, change `Comparator<Map.Entry<? super K, ? super V>>` to `Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>`. Just to get started, I always have trouble to wrap my mind around it (super vs extends).

Comment: It would help very much if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The implementation of `mapSort` does not really matter, e.g...

Comment: Thank you JoD, what you suggested actually solved the problem single handedly. I am not sure exactly why though.

Comment: Wait a minute! Duplicates? As per Java doc [Maps can have no duplicates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)! If you want such a feature, maybe investigate [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html)

Comment: Maps can have no duplicate keys, but when we are talking about TreeMaps, then two different keys can be the same in some arbitrary comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Copied from my comment]

For the signature for sortMap, change `Comparator<Map.Entry<? super K, ? super V>>` to `Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>`. Just to get started, I always have trouble to wrap my mind around it (`super` vs `extends`).

[Update]

There is a nice section about `<? super XXX>` and `<? extends XXX>` in Effective Java, 2nd Edition: "Item 28: Use bounded wildcards to increase API flexibility", particularly where they talk about 'PECS' - Producer-Extends, Consumer-Super.

I still would need to research better as to the why's in this case, but at least we have a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

`Comparator<Map.Entry<Event,Entry>>` is not a subtype of `Comparator<Map.Entry<? super K, ? super V>>`, because the type parameter of `Comparator` is different. It's just like how `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` because `String` and `Object` are different, even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`.

If you want to use wildcards for the parameters of `Map.Entry`, you will also need a wildcard at the level of the parameter of `Comparator`, like this:

```
Comparator<? extends Map.Entry<? super K, ? super V>>
```